# Pronunciation of "Wiki"

Tags: pronunciation, neologisms

We were discussing the merits of buying a team collaboration tool (Confluence) today, when we were completely sidetracked by the pronouncation "wiki".

Most of the folks on the team say it's pronounced **"whicky"**; that's what Wikipedia calls it, Wikileaks, etc.

However, a few stalwarts insist that, since its etymology is Hawiian, it's actually pronounced **"weekee"**. They say the "big brands" like Wikipedia who insist upon calling themselves "whicky-pee-dee-ah" don't change the fact that "wiki" is pronounced "weekee".

Anyway, given that this is a neologism, what's the proper pronuncation? Is it an accent/regional preference?

Comment: As Hellion's answer notes, some English dialects exhibit a difference between "wh" and lone "w" at the start of a word - the former is pronounced something like (and in many cases originally spelt as) "hw". You may want to change the spelling in your question to "wicky" unless you specifically do pronounce it like that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think if you were to pronounce it "weekee" you would either come off as being pedantic, or from another country with an adorable accent, or you would spend a lot of time explaining what you meant — to people who then would say, "Oh, you mean a *wiki*!"

I've given up on a lot of "correct" pronunciations. For example, the correct pronunciation for "acclimated" is uh•CLIMB•uh•ted, not ACK•luh•may•ted. But I've just grown weary of that discussion. And don't even get me started on American mispronunciations of Japanese words: the American SUE-moh instead of the Japanese s'MOH for sumo, harry-carry for the correct harakiri (as long as you pronounce the "r"s as soft taps of the tongue on the palate), etc.

Comment: FWIW, Merriam-Webster gives your supposed “wrong” pronunciations first for all the words you cite: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acclimated http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sumo http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hara-kiri So if people are pronouncing those words “wrong”, it’s because the authority on pronunciation, i.e. dictionaries, is telling them to.

Comment: @nohat: Online dictionaries especially reflect current usages. Like me, they've given up on usages that were once given first. But as for the Japanese words, I'm talking about Japanese pronunciations — read my last sentence again. I speak Japanese, and I assure you your source is simply wrong. I don't deny that is how Americans pronounce those words, but I certainly doubt that the reason is because dictionaries are telling them to. People hear the mispronunciations and mimic them, and dictionaries eventually record it all. You put the cart before the horse.

Comment: (1) I would not call the pronunciations of _sumo_ and _harakiri_ in English “mispronunciations” because it is just natural that words with Japanese origin are pronounced in English way when used as an English word.  There are many reasons why _sumo_ is not pronounced as [sɯ̀móó] and _harakiri_ not as [hàɽákíɽí] in English.  (2) By the way, the Merriam-Webster dictionary does not say anything about the Japanese pronunciation of _sumo_ or _harakiri_ and therefore I am not completely sure why nohat cited it.

Comment: I cited Merriam-Webster because it is an authority on how to pronounce words in American English, regardless of their origin, Japanese or otherwise. Words always change pronunciation when they are borrowed into another language. That's how language works. Calling it "mispronunciation" is like calling French a "mispronunciation" of Latin. ***I*** can assure ***you*** that Merriam-Webster's reporting of how to pronounce the *English* words *sumo* and *hara-kiri* are unimpeachably correct.

Comment: @nohat: Unimpeachably correct? That's a bold statement. But if you wish to accept Merriam-Webster as your personal savior, that is up to you. Me, I think there are no assertions that cannot be debated. It's what venues like this one are for. Otherwise the only answer to any question would be "look it up in Merriam-Webster." But what do you do when dictionaries disagree? They do, you know. And thumping your Merriam-Webster like a Baptist with a bible won't help.

Comment: I think we know the answer to "what do you do when dictionaries disagree" is you look to common usage, which we both already agreed matches what Merriam-Webster says. In fact, as far as I can tell, the *only* source which disavows the correctness of the pronunciation of the English words *sumo* as /ˈsuːmoʊ/, *hara-kiri* as /hærɪˈkɪriː/, and *acclimated* as /ˈækləmeɪtəd/ is **you**. All the other dictionaries I looked in—*American Heritage*, *Webster’s New World*, *Random House*, *Oxford American*—agree with Merriam-Webster. On what basis are you correct and everyone else wrong?

Comment: @nohat: I stated the terms of my opinion in my response. I pronounce the words as I hear them in Japanese. Some people pronounce French or Spanish words as they are pronounced in the original language. These are matters of personal choice. If the rest of America wants to have a tin ear, so be it. Which was pretty much my point. What you fail to realize, or acknowledge, is that very, very few people get their pronunciations out of a dictionary — except for arguments like this one.

Comment: @Robusto: @nohat's point is that the English language is defined by its speakers. You're right that we're not pronouncing those Japanese words like the Japanese do, but that's because we're speaking English. If you pronounce it the way the Japanese do you're not "pronouncing it right", you're putting a Japanese word in place of an English word (that has a Japanese origin). America does not "have a tin ear". As you said, people hear how others pronounce it and repeat it. Maybe the first guy who said "sumo" in English "mis-pronounced" it, but everyone after that was merely pronouncing it.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: I already stated that in my first comment to nohat: "I don't deny that is how Americans pronounce those words, but I certainly doubt that the reason is because dictionaries are telling them to. People hear the mispronunciations and mimic them, and dictionaries eventually record it all." (And, yes, Americans *do* have a tin ear when it comes to other languages.) In any case,  that's all I'm going to say on the topic.

Comment: The point is that they are not “mispronunciations”—they are borrowed words. It is characterizing them as “mispronunciations” which is having a “tin ear” for how language actually works.

Comment: @nohat: Wait, what? That made no sense at all. But I hope it made you feel better.

Comment: I agree with @nohat: these are borrowed words, not mispronunciations. Should we consider the Spanish *estándar* for *standard* or the Japanese [アイスクリーム (aisu kurīmu)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gairaigo_and_wasei-eigo_terms#Examples) for *ice cream* as mispronunciations of English?

Comment: Listening to *sumo* on [forvo.com](http://forvo.com/word/%E7%9B%B8%E6%92%B2/#ja) , I would say the pronunciation *s'MOH* sounds almost as far from the original Japanese to me as *SOO-mo* (nobody says *SUE-mo*). The first syllable really does have a vowel in it, although not one that English speakers can pronounce. And Japanese, like French, does not have phonemic syllabic stress.

Comment: @PeterShor: The pronunciation by strawberrybrown on the site you linked is closest, to my ear, to what I normally hear from Japanese native speakers. Remember that every syllable takes beat, and the stretching of the first syllable to cover the beat, while all but dropping the vowel sound, yields her rendition: *s'MOH*.

Answer (score 10):

I would claim that they're two different words from two different languages. *Wiki* means quick. Wiki is used to refer to collaboratively edited media. They are two different things.

For the record, I live in Hawai'i and am fairly pedantic about my pronunciation, e.g. I pronounce Ho'okipa as Ho-o-kipa and not Ho-kipa as most hoales do or Hoo-kipa like the tourists do. *i* is definitely pronounced *ee* and your friends are definitely right about the Hawai'ian word. It has no bearing whatsoever. It's Wikipedia, not quick.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of words whose current pronunciation bears little or no relationship to their etymology.  Personally I don't aspirate the "W" either, so I say it's "wick-ee".

Comment: As for W versus WH, in the OP's accent it must not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Wiktionary is an adequate reference for this case: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wiki, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

The only adequate reference for this must be the correspondence between Patrick Taylor and [Ward Cunningham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward_Cunningham), who was the person to coin the term Wiki.

From [Correspondence on the Etymology of Wiki](http://c2.com/doc/etymology.html):

**The Question (by Patrick Taylor)**

> I was wondering if you could fill us in here at the dictionary with any more details on your use of the Hawaiian word to the site and the web machinery. What year did this take place? In 1995? Do you have a long-standing interest in the Hawaiian language, or did you come by the Hawaiian word by other means? Did you intend the word to be pronounced as wee-kee (rhyming with leaky) or as wick-ey (rhyming with sticky)?".

**The Answer (by [Ward Cunningham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward_Cunningham))**

> *What year did this take place? In 1995?*
>
> Yes. I wrote similar programs earlier but they did not run on the web
>   and they were not called wiki.
>
> *Do you have a long-standing interest in the Hawaiian language, or did
>   you come by the Hawaiian word by other means?*
>
> Wiki wiki is the first Hawai'ian term I learned on my first visit to
>   the islands. The airport counter agent directed me to take the wiki
>   wiki bus between terminals. I said what? He explained that wiki wiki
>   meant quick. I was to find the quick bus. I did pick up a book about
>   the language before my return home. I learned many things from this
>   but wiki wiki is the word that sticks the most.
>
> *Did you intend the word to be pronounced as wee-kee (rhyming with
>   leaky) or as wick-ey (rhyming with sticky)?*
>
> I believe the former is the proper pronunciation though I've been
>   known to use the latter. My preference would be that the word be
>   pronounced as a Hawai'ian would, and that wick-ey be an acceptable
>   alternative.